# npm run publish doesn't do anything when I push repository from master branch to gh-pages

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-pages, deploying

While trying to run publish.sh file in VS Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# abort on errors
set -e

# build
npm run docs:build

# navigate into the build output directory
cd docs/.vuepress/dist

# if you are deploying to a custom domain
# echo 'www.example.com' > CNAME

git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'deploy'

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io
# git push -f git@github.com:boldak/<USERNAME>.github.io.git master

# if you are deploying to https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>
git push -f https://github.com/shunichkaaaa/edu_db_labs_IO-12_Group-4 master:gh-pages

cd -
```

I meet the problem, that npm run do completely ANYTHING. It doesn't return a mistake, nor creates the second branch on GitHub as it should be.

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnwIH.png)

As was advised on one of the websites I tried to set npm ignore-scripts value to false.
`npm config set ignore-scripts false`
But it already was set to false.

I can host my service locally while using `npm run docs:dev`.

Switching from VS Code terminal to Windows Command Prompt just repeated the previous problem.

So any opinions on this count??